# Swift noob: How to run the tests of a pod?

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to clone this pod: https://github.com/movielala/YoutubeSourceParserKit

However, I've never written or ran tests before in Xcode. I have cloned the repo, but when I open it in Xcode I see a bunch of errors in the test file[image]

Could someone provide me with step by step instructions on how to run the test suite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an easy fix. You need to select the file Youtube.swift in you project navigator. Then display the File Inspector in the right side bar of your project and check it for the YoutubeSourceParswerKitTests. Make sure to clean your build and recompile. After that you should be fine to run your tests.

[image]

Comment: BTW: To actually run tests you will need to create a new scheme based on YoutubeSourceparserKitTests. Then in build settings for that scheme you need to adjust the path for the scheme's Info.plist. 
Once you got that going and can build you click the diamonds in the code editor for each test. If the test is successful, the diamond turns green.

Comment: thanks a lot @caxix . whoever wrote this pod didn't test it well at all... the assertions never get executed because the class calls `dispatch_async` and the tests seem to just ignore anything inside of that. ughhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh